# Resteasy client : How to set Context Params

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using Resteasy client to run test cases for my Service. In application We set context Params in a session check filter,(which implements ContainerRequestFilter). I'm trying to set the same, in Resteasy client, using by adding a ClientRequestFilter implementation, but the property is not recognized, in the service call.

//Resteasy client calling logic

```
ResteasyClient resteasyClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        resteasyClient.register(new MyClientRequestFilter());
resteasyClient.target("http://localhost:" + port + "/myPath").request()
.post(Entity.json(authorization_reqParams)).readEntity(String.class));
```

//filter

```
 public class MyClientRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter
    {

        @Override
        public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
        {
       requestContext.setProperty("CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE", "myCustomValue");

        }
    }
```

//Rest service method

```
     @POST
        @Path("/myPath")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response subpartner(Authorization_ReqParams authorizationReqParams, @Context HttpHeaders headers,
                @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response)
        {
        String myAttribute= request.getAttribute("CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE"); 
//myAttribute is returned as null always

        //additional logic

        }
```

I'm able to set&get Header paramets  with the same implementation, but Request param is always read as null.
How can I set the request context params ?

Answer (score 0):

In `MyClientRequestFilter` you add a propery to the request object. What you really want is to send a header instead.

Try this instead:

```
@Override
public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
    headers.add("CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE", "myCustomValue");
}
```

And read it like this:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/myPath")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response subpartner(Authorization_ReqParams authorizationReqParams, @Context HttpHeaders headers,
                @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response)
        {
            String myAttribute= headers.getRequestHeader("CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE"); 

        //additional logic

        }
```

Comment: The request headers, I'm able to set & get. But need to set the attribute in request context , because the REST calls are following it and I've to create this client to validate all the calls.
Any idea, why am I not able to get those context params ?

Comment: As far as I know you use two different systems. Client and server. The client adds a property to it's context. When the service receives  this request it doesn't know about the client's context. Those contexts are not the same (like two different java object pointing to a different location in the memory).